# Select * FROM table WHERE date between two selected dates

Tags: php, select

I want to display data between two dates. But I want to be able to select those two dates. I don`t know where or how to store those dates in order to be able to add a variable in the SELECT. Please be very specific when you answer. Thank you!
This is how my code looks like:

```
<div class ="row">


<div class ="col-md-3">


    <form action="" method="post" role="form">

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="startdate">Start date:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate" >

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="enddate">Ending date:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate" >

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />


    </form>

</div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<!-- Default panel contents -->


<!-- Table -->
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Nume</th>
        <th>Prenume</th>
        <th>Serviciu</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Ora</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </thead>



    <?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM rezervari2 ORDER BY data ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

            $list = data_rezervare($dbc, $list['idrezervare']);
    ?>   

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $list['nume']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $list['prenume']; ?></td>            
        <td><?php echo $list['serviciu']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $list['data']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $list['ora']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $list['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $list['telefon']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $list['status']; ?></td> 
    </tr>

     <?php  } ?>     

</table>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BETWEEN` clause:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

```
SELECT dateCol FROM tableName WHERE dateCol BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-27';
```

Almost any info about SQL syntax for MySQL can be found on MySQL dev site: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/

To get the values from you form fields you will have to use `$_GET["field_name"]` or `$_POST["field_name"]` values acoording to the value of your form's method attribute. The values will be available when you submit the form.

```
$startdate = $_POST["startdate"];
```

As an advice, avoid concatenating user values in you queries. Or else, you will open your app for SQL injection.

Take a look at `mysqli` functions (yes, with an "i" at the end) or, even better, `PDO`:

http://php.net/manual/book.mysqli.php
http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php

Comment: I know about the BETWEEN clause. My problem is not that. My problem is that I want to be able to insert the date in that input box.

Comment: So you want to get the `$_GET["field_name"]` or `$_POST["field_name"]` values acoording to the value of your form's `method` attribute.

Comment: Yes. I want to get the startdate and enddate from those two inputboxes. I am not sure I did well using an form also. If you have a better solution to make those 2 inputboxes I am openminded. If not just tell me what to write and where in my code. Thanks!