# mysql php pdo select a part of row value date record

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date, pdo

I want to select a part of a record in database. The record i want to select from is date.

The record date is this format `07/02/2015`.
I want to have a select option where i can put option of year and month to used as parameter for the search.I want to know a select query for ff.

1. How can I select a specific year from the record(annual report)

   I want to select all record in database with the current year, or with the year 2014.
2. How can i select a specific month from the record(monthly report)

   I want to select all record in database with the current month and current year or with a X month and a X year

Comment: Could you provide an example of the structure of the database table?

Comment: i have a column that is date from this column i want to select a specific year or specific month i have answers below and i am trying them out

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN` Keyword

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE dateCol BETWEEN '01-01-2014' AND '31-12-2014';
```

for reference 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

[Select * FROM table WHERE date between two selected dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489555/select-from-table-where-date-between-two-selected-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(COLNAME, '%d/%m/%y'), '%Y-%m-%d'))  = '2014'

SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(COLNAME, '%d/%m/%y'), '%Y-%m-%d'))  = x
```

Comment: should i change `DATE_FORMAT` and `STR_TO_DATE` i alway get 0 rowcount

Comment: Please post the sql query you are trying to execute.

Comment: $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM date_tbl where YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_filed, '%d/%m/%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')) = :year"); $stmt->bindValue(':year', $year, PDO::PARAM_STR);